# What is .zix type of file and how to open it?

Tags: extract, file-extension

I am having a tough time searching through internet , "How to extract a `.zix` file ?".
I herd of `winzix` but that's more of a **BAD** - ware (virus, adware ,...etc) then,
 after a real hard time I found `unZixwin` that read the files present in my .zix file but gave some errors while extraction, after searching I read that `This software is highly experimental use it on your own risk!` darn it! I am still searching that software (or atleast a way) that extracts .zix files.

Comment: You say there were errors please provide them.

Answer (score 2):

Winrar should extract it, but this type of file is generally used in torrent networks and it tells you to use the program winzix but it is adware, if winrar wont open then your probably never get it opened

Comment: Aww man! I really hoped for an answer! :[

Comment: Did you read the first part? (`Winrar should extract it`).

Comment: @MukulKumar: Have you at least **tried** what Andrew suggested? You could also take a look at the file in an editor and look for clues about the actual format. It might simply have a "wrong" file extension.

Comment: I tried everything before asking this question, opening that file in every editor (winrar, 7-zip, winuha, universal extractor and unzixwin) everywhere the file was unreadable accept for that unzixwin which gave errors while extraction

Comment: the file is either corrupt or is fake did you download it via a torrent?

Comment: @AndrewCrawford yes, but if file is corrupt then unzixwin should also have given an error, but unzixwin reads the file but is unable to extract. That means, either my search is incomplete or the file is fake

Comment: yes i said corrupt or fake

Comment: Ok, I got wrong version of unzixwin, the correct one extracted the files and I got my files YAY! neither fake nor corrupted

Comment: Please share Unzixwin version